# Changing the portlet URL

Tags: url, liferay, portlet

In the `doView` method, is there a way to change the current Portlet URL with an external URL (like : www.google.fr) and then refresh it (so that it gets the new content) ?

Regards.

Comment: you can forward the request to other site, is it that what you want?

Comment: @FelixChristy : how can I do that kind of redirection without "quitting" the portlet/portal?

Answer (score 1):

I am taking this back. What you can do is that in the processAction(), at the end you can do actionResponse.sendRedirect(String url),

This will not call the doView() method at all, if you want to do in the doView() only, then I guess, you have to use the javascript to change the window.location. This will redirect to www.google.fr.

Let me know in case of any details.

Comment: How can I do it ? the response.sendRedirect is not working in my JSP

Comment: did you get any exception? could you please provide the output?

Comment: I have no exception generated for that instruction.

Comment: @Jeff: You can't do this redirect in your jsp, Felix is asking you to do this in processAction. The reason is that, while your jsp is processed, part of the page might already be delivered to the browser - including the HTTP headers. The headers are where the redirection is being put to, and if it's not available any more, the redirect would not work but rather trigger an error (like: "response already committed" or similar)